# Numba Unknown attribute 'search' of type Module(<module 're' from 'C:\\Users\\HP\\anaconda3\\lib\\re.py'>) Regex is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

1.My code is not working in Numba but working fine in python Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step:     nopython frontend)
2. Explain how to use function Regex(re) which are not supported by Numba

**code**
As you can see in my code what IAM trying to do

```
import re
@nb.njit
def search_patterns():
    text = 'software testing is fun?'
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search('software', text):
            print("Matched")
patterns = ['software testing', 'guru99']
import timeit


start = time.time()
search_patterns()
end = time.time()
```

**Output**
this is the Output i got as a resulrt

```
**TypingError**                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-4e8f7643bb52> in <module>
     10 
     11 start = time.time()
---> 12 search_patterns()
     13 end = time.time()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    413                 e.patch_message(msg)
    414 
--> 415             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    416         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    417             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    356                 raise e
    357             else:
--> 358                 reraise(type(e), e, None)
    359 
    360         argtypes = []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
     78         value = tp()
     79     if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
---> 80         raise value.with_traceback(tb)
     81     raise value
     82 

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'search' of type Module(<module 're' from 'C:\\Users\\HP\\anaconda3\\lib\\re.py'>)

File "<ipython-input-14-4e8f7643bb52>", line 6:
def search_patterns():
    <source elided>
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search('software', text):
        ^

During: typing of get attribute at <ipython-input-14-4e8f7643bb52> (6)

File "<ipython-input-14-4e8f7643bb52>", line 6:
def search_patterns():
    <source elided>
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search('software', text):
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/5minguide.html#will-numba-work-for-my-code) say, "*if your code is numerically orientated (does a lot of math), uses NumPy a lot and/or has a lot of loops, then Numba is often a good choice.*"

In your case, the internals of `re.search()` are written in C (at least in the CPython reference implementation), so there's no way Numba can help there.